# Perl script to print the matching line from a text file

Tags: regex, perl

Text file lines:

```
2018-03-02 10:56:06,808 DEBUG [com.server.hdmi.xmlgenerator.XMLGenerator] XMLGenerator TLS ID size 142392_REQ_2018-03-02T09-53-18-991+10-00:3561
2018-03-02 10:56:02,074 DEBUG [com.server.hdmi.xmlgenerator.XMLGenerator] XMLGenerator TLS ID size 142401_REQ_2018-03-02T09-53-20-607+10-00:1444
2018-03-02 10:56:02,074 INFO  [com.server.hdmi.xmlgenerator.XMLGenerator] Exit createDOMTreefromXMLGenerator
2018-03-02 10:56:02,074 DEBUG [com.server.hdmi.xmlgenerator.XMLGenerator] generating file for TranID:142401:D:/InterfaceData/Address\142401_RESP_2018-03-02T10-55-35-035+10-00.xml
```

My script:

```
my $LogDir = '\\\\server\\ddrive\support\purushoth\log';
    if(-e $LogDir)

    {                       
        opendir(DIR, $LogDir);
        while (defined(my $file = readdir (DIR)))   
        {           
            if ($file =~ m/server/i)
            {
            my $fullfilename = $LogDir."\\".$file;
            my @logFileLines = ();
            open (LOGFILE, "$fullfilename") or die "Could not open file";
                {
                    @logFileLines = <LOGFILE>;

                }
                close(LOGFILE);

                my $temp2 = 0;
                foreach my $line1 (@logFileLines)
                {
                    chomp($line1);      
                    if ( $line1 =~ (m!/^(\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}\s{1}\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2})\s+.*XMLGenerator\s+TLS\s+ID\s+size\s+/.*\$!);
                    {
                    print "the line match in the server log:  $line1\n";
                    }
                 }            
            }
        }
    }
```

From the log file, I want to print only matching lines like this. I tried with my script, but it's not working.

```
2018-03-02 10:56:06,808 DEBUG [com.server.hdmi.xmlgenerator.XMLGenerator] XMLGenerator TLS ID size 142392_REQ_2018-03-02T09-53-18-991+10-00:3561
```

Please help me to read such lines and print it. And also i want to assign the last part of this line.

```
142392_REQ_2018-03-02T09-53-18-991+10-00:3561
```

Comment: Why do think you need to write a script? Can you not use grep?

Comment: @JimGarrison I am new to perl. So not sure what grep will do. And also, i want to print the line in a HTML file to show as report

Comment: what do you want to fetch the line might be keywords???

Comment: where to assign the line `its already in the input`

Comment: Your regex has forward slashes `/` (not as delimiters, which are `!`) while the line you show you want to match doesn't. You also have a dollar sign at the end of the regex (`\$`), which also isn't in the line. So the regex is not going to match that line. The code seems fine

Comment: You show the line with quotes -- does it really have quotes? The regex doesn't allow for them. Do the lines really start with spaces (as "_Text file lines_" do)?  The regex doesn't.  Other than this, it seems that you need to remove the two `/` and the `\$` from the regex.

Comment: @zdim Please suggest

Comment: I did -- remove `/` and `\$` from regex.  Also, regex doesn't account for `,808` in the time stamp. Altogether: `/^(\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}\s+\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2},\d{3})\s+.*XMLGenerator\s+TLS\s+ID\s+size.*/`  This works in my test (for that line you show). I didn't test the whole code (which seems fine to me), just the regex.

Comment: There's also a stray semicolon at the end of the `if` statement which means it does nothing and the subsequent code block will always happen

Comment: This question looks awfully similar to your last one, [Perl script to read a line in file with pattern matching and print](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49107903/perl-script-to-read-a-line-in-file-with-pattern-matching-and-print)...?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the issue is with the regular expression, then here's the small sample with the correctly working one:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
my @lines = (
    '2018-03-02 10:56:06,808 DEBUG [com.server.hdmi.xmlgenerator.XMLGenerator] XMLGenerator TLS ID size 142392_REQ_2018-03-02T09-53-18-991+10-00:3561',
    '2018-03-02 10:56:02,074 DEBUG [com.server.hdmi.xmlgenerator.XMLGenerator] XMLGenerator TLS ID size 142401_REQ_2018-03-02T09-53-20-607+10-00:1444',
    '2018-03-02 10:56:02,074 INFO  [com.server.hdmi.xmlgenerator.XMLGenerator] Exit createDOMTreefromXMLGenerator',
    '2018-03-02 10:56:02,074 DEBUG [com.server.hdmi.xmlgenerator.XMLGenerator] generating file for TranID:142401:D:/InterfaceData/Address\142401_RESP_2018-03-02T10-55-35-035+10-00.xml'
);

foreach my $line (@lines) {
    if ($line =~ /^(\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2} \d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}).*XMLGenerator TLS ID size (.*)/) {
        print "Timestamp: $1, TLS ID: $2\n";
    } elsif ($line =~ /^(\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2} \d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}).*generating file for.*\\(.*)/) {
        print "Timestamp: $1, filename: $2\n";
    }
}
```

Comment: This works! thanks. Now i want to print a particular string from a line after "backslash"

Comment: 2018-03-02 07:11:54,040 DEBUG [com.Get.xmlgenerator.XMLGenerator] generating file for TranID:142283:D:/Data/Address\142283_RESP_2018-03-02T07-11-09-009+10-00.xml

Comment: i want to print only :      142283_RESP_2018-03-02T07-11-09-009+10-00.xml

Comment: @Purushothaman I've updated the source snipped in the answer: `$line =~ /^(\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2} \d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}).*generating file for.*\\(.*)/`

Comment: the line will be like:

Comment: 2018-03-02 07:11:54,040 DEBUG [com.hdmi.xmlgenerator.XMLGenerator] generating file for TranID:142283:D:/InterfaceData/Address\142283_RESP_2018-03-02T07-11-09-009+10-00.xml

Comment: i want ro print only the .xml file name

Comment: 142283_RESP_2018-03-02T07-11-09-009+10-00.xml

Comment: if ($line =~ /^(\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2} \d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}).*generating file for.*\\(.*)/) 
      {
       print "Timestamp: $1, filename: $2\n";
      }

Comment: @Purushothaman Code snippet in the answer has the working example.

Comment: I am trying to split a server name and printing it. But I am getting number "2" while printing. Please advice

Comment: my $jboss_server = split(',',$jboss_servers);

Comment: print "$jboss_server\n";

Comment: In Config file: jboss_servers=app624,app621

Comment: $jboss_servers is printing correctly app624,app621... After split, its not printing properly